# React Native and Django Rest Framework connection problem at local,Cors settings

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I am building a react native project. I have already done the same project's website. I deployed it on Heroku and without any problem it works.
When I try to fetch data on local server with react native app, It does not work but when I use deployed project url it works.

For example;

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sosyalmedya/ does not work.

http://mydeployedwebsite.com/api/sosyalmedya/ work.

My settings.py is the same with deployed one.

In my settings.py I have added these;

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Edit!!!
There is no problem with React. The problem occurs when I try to fetch data in React Native

Comment: Define "does not work". It returns 404 or the server is not reachable at all?

Comment: I get this 'Error: Network Error'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem just replacing localhost url.
In React Native,as I saw, we have to change localhost url to 10.0.2.2 to fetch data.
In my case;
http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/sosyalmedya/ worked.